# Is there a way to run a jar inside a vm with gitlab-ci

Tags: java, gitlab-ci

I have a jar inside VM which needs to be run via gitlab-ci pipeline. Is there any way to exec into the VM and run jar inside VM through gitlab pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you use Docker as VM, you can setup a runner that uses docker images.

That runner could use an image that contains a java runtime to launch `java -jar yourfile.jar`.

Current supported java docker image can be found on the hub, e.g. https://hub.docker.com/_/ibmjava